# Script replacing value from variables into document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to undertake following action: Get values from text inputs, then check if first of them occurs in whole document. If it occurs in the document I would like to replace all instances of it by value of second variable.

Code in snipet is not correct cause function replace doesn't work...
Has anyone idea how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var replaced = $('#replaced').val();
    var modified = $('#modified').val();
    
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if($( ".entireSite:contains(" + replaced + ")" ).text() === '') {
          alert('there is no wanted word/phrase at the website');
        } else {
          $('.entireSite').text().replace(replaced, modified);
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="replaced" value="word/phrase to modify"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="modified" value="new word/phrase"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    
<div class="entireSite">    
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed sollicitudin 
  lectus. Sed libero tellus, sodales quis eros
  eu, vestibulum interdum nibh. Nunc Lorem quis 
  diam vitae enim finibus pretium ut a ipsum. 
  Cras ut ullamcorper mi, vel fringilla augue. 
  Pellentesque Lorem consequat vulputate ipsum 
  sit amet faucibus. Aliquam erat orci, cursus 
  id tempor bibendum, condimentum vitae enim.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are only setting the variables "replaced" and "modified" when the document is loaded, not when you click on the button. 
This is an explanation to @Phani Kumar M's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As .text() is a function (which returns a value) you are replacing a copy of the text of that value. You should save that result (for example in a variable named replacedText)and assign it again with .text( replacedText )

Answer (score 0):

Here we go!

I fixed some issues on your code, this way you can do it ^^

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var toReplace = $('#toReplace');
    var replaceWith = $('#replaceWith');
    var par = $('.entireSite p');
    
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    
    var one = toReplace.val();
    var two = replaceWith.val();   
    while(par.text().indexOf(one) != -1){
    var txt = par.text();
    par.text(txt.replace(one,two));  
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="toReplace" placeholder="word/phrase to modify"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="replaceWith" placeholder="new word/phrase"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
    
<div class="entireSite">    
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed sollicitudin 
  lectus. Sed libero tellus, sodales quis eros
  eu, vestibulum interdum nibh. Nunc Lorem quis 
  diam vitae enim finibus pretium ut a ipsum. 
  Cras ut ullamcorper mi, vel fringilla augue. 
  Pellentesque Lorem consequat vulputate ipsum 
  sit amet faucibus. Aliquam erat orci, cursus 
  id tempor bibendum, condimentum vitae enim.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. It is also useful in case of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="replaced" value="Lorem">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="modified" value="Parag">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">

  <div class="entireSite">
    <p id="finalResult">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed sollicitudin lectus. Sed libero tellus, sodales quis eros eu, vestibulum interdum nibh. Nunc Lorem quis diam vitae enim finibus pretium ut a ipsum. Cras ut ullamcorper mi, vel fringilla
      augue. Pellentesque Lorem consequat vulputate ipsum sit amet faucibus. Aliquam erat orci, cursus id tempor bibendum, condimentum vitae enim.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var replaced = $('#replaced').val();
    var modified = $('#modified').val();
    var finalText = $('#finalResult').text();

    if (finalText.indexOf(replaced) >= 0) {
      var temp = new RegExp(replaced, "g");
     $("#finalResult").text(finalText.replace(temp, modified));
    }
  });
});
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/31mLuxdh/1/)** to play with.